# emulate telnet over ssh

Tags: ssh, telnet, emulator

I have a client/server application that work over a telnet connection, and it does not support SSH. Basically the client opens a telnet connection to the server, which starts a specific shell, and the client sends commands over the telnet connection to that shell. The problem is that I need to make this work over a ssh connection, and the remote server does not have telnet services, so I cannot use a tunnel over the ssh connection. I need some kind of telnet emulator that will offer a telnet endpoint to the client, while connecting through ssh to the server. Is there any way to do this?

thanks

Comment: When can’t improve the client and it requires a telnet connection you will probably need to install a telnet server. You can then use port forwarding over SSH to ensure transport encryption (or preferably set up  a VPN connection to do the same) and won’t even  need to open up the telnet port to the public at large.

Comment: I know, but installing a telnet server is not an option. That’s why I’m looking for a way to emulate a telnet server that  send all commands through ssh to the shell in the remote server.

Comment: Why does it need to be ssh, to encrypt it? telnet over TLS (telnets) is a thing. Does the application implement its own telnet server and/or client, or does it just run whatever telnet client binary is available?

Comment: The application inplements it’s own telnet client, and on the server side the only connection I’ve got available is SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a normal case for port forwarding over ssh.

A server `<ip>` has ssh endpoint opened and an application server listening on Telnet port 23.

A client has an application client which should connect to `<ip>:23`. Also client has nothing listening on port 23.

Let's establish port forwarding from server to client:

```
ssh -N -L 23:127.0.0.1:23 user@<ip> >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Here we:

- connect to the server `<ip>` as user `user`;
- put ssh session into background;
- redirect ssh session's output into /dev/null to avoid any messages on console;
- forward port 23 from the server's localhost to the client (your application server should listen on all IP interfaces, including 127.0.0.1)

Now application client should connect to the address `127.0.0.1:23` to work with the application server.

### Update

As per explanations, we have a telnet only capable client software and ssh only capable server. And client should be able to access the server.

As it happens, such solution does exist. From [manual](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/Manual.htm?SSH_via_Telnet):

> **SSH/Telnet gateway**
>
> In the Telnet-DeleGate (DeleGate server for Telnet clients), a host name prefixed with "-ssh" and "." (as "-ssh.host") implies a SSH server on the host. In access to such a server, Telnet-DeleGate works as a gateway between the SSH server and a Telnet client. For example, using a Telnet-DeleGate configured like follows, Telnet clients can login to a SSH server on host as user as follows:
>
> ```
> % delegated -P8023 SERVER=telnet://-ssh
> % telnet -l user@host localhost 8023
> ```

Meet **[DeleGate](http://delegate.hpcc.jp/delegate/)**

Comment: That would be ok, except for the fact that telnet is no running on the server. That’s why I need to emulate a telnet and send the commands the client generate to the server’s she’ll using ssh

Comment: @JoseLMartinez-Avial When your server application is started, which port is it listening on? Also what OS is on the server?

Comment: There is no server as such. The applications connects through telnet and runs shell commands and programs. So is no a server per se, just a command shell. The OS is Solaris

Comment: @JoseLMartinez-Avial Posted an update. Exactly what you were looking for...